# toggle div js in joomla not working

Tags: javascript, joomla

My toggle div js is not working in joomla. When the js code is in the head of the page it works fine, when its in an external file it doesn't. All my links seem fine:

Joomla template - Index.php:

```
<?php
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript( '/js/togglediv.js' )
 ?>
```

Joomla template - templateDetails.xml:

```
<filename>js/togglediv.js</filename>
```

togglediv.js:

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("box");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
```

}

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a>    
<div id="box">hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
width: 304px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid green;
display: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine, but to be sure, view source on the rendered page to see if the path is correct.

Comment: Are you sure the JS is loading correctly when it's held externally?  Joomla likes mangling tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full address for `addScript()`.  Use JURI for this:

```
$document->addScript( JURI::Root().SERVER_PATH_TO_JS_FOLDER.'/js/togglediv.js' )
```

Your JS in the HTML is a bit off.  Try this:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle()">show</a>
```

There also doesn't seem to be anything with the `id` `box`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please explain it a little more for me? What is JURI? Can I not use a relative path? etc. Thanks.

Comment: Well this `$document->addScript( JURI::Root().'js/togglediv.js' )`
gives me `<script src="http://localhost:8888/testsite/js/togglediv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` which is correct but the script still isn't working!

Comment: Yes, two of them, the ones I added.

Comment: Ahhhh. sorry didn't look at you previous post. Made the changes and amended my first post to reflect the missing div - its still not working though!